# Laravel user permission to update own post

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles

I'm following a tutorial on Laravel gates where users with the permission 'update-post' are allowed to edit any post in the database. In addition, any user regardless of permissions can edit posts they've submitted.

app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php:

```
Gate::define('update-post', function ($user, \App\Post $post) {
     return $user->hasAccess(['update-post']) or $user->id == $post->user_id;
});
```

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/edit/{post}', 'PostController@edit')
    ->name('edit_post')
    ->middleware('can:update-post,post');

Route::post('/edit/{post}', 'PostController@update')
    ->name('update_post')
    ->middleware('can:update-post,post');
```

What I'm looking for is a way to add a new permission, say 'update-own-post', where only users with that permission are allowed to edit their own posts.

So, a moderator for example would have the permission 'update-post' that allows them to edit all posts. A regular user will only be able to edit their own post if they are assigned the new permission 'update-own-post' but not every user as is currently implemented.

What's the best way to go about implementing this change in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Gate you want to check the type of user, so they should be able to edit if one of the following are true:

1. `$user->hasAccess(['update-post'])`
2. `$user->id == $post->user_id`
3. `$user->isModerator()`

I don't know how you have your user types set up, but I would recommend adding a method to your user model that checks the type of user, and if the type of user is 'moderator' or whatever name you chose, it should return true.

You would be left with something similar to:

```
Gate::define('update-post', function ($user, \App\Post $post) {
    return $user->hasAccess(['update-post']) || $user->id == $post->user_id || $user->isModerator();
});
```

Edit -- answer from comments

Based on your comment you can accomplish it like so, here is the cleaned up code:

```
Gate::define('update-post', function ($user, \App\Post $post) { 
    return ($user->id == $post->user_id && $user->hasAccess(['update-own-post'])) || $user->hasAccess(['update-post']); 
});
```

The reason that this works is because your checking if `{first condition} OR {second condition}` meets the criteria.  If the first block is true, the second block won't even be executed; however, if the first block isn't true it will then check the second to see if it is true.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. I was able to accomplish what I need by changing the gate to the following:        `Gate::define('update-post', function ($user, \App\Post $post) {
            if(($user->id == $post->user_id) && ($user->hasAccess(['update-own-post'])))
                return true;
            else if ($user->hasAccess(['update-post']))
                return true;
        });` Would appreciate a cleaner code though.

Comment: I'm glad you got it worked out, check my code for a cleaner version of what you have.  Also I recommend looking into OR ('`||`') in PHP, it will help you get rid of some of the extra condition checks. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php